# Как распарсить один запрос с возможными разными значениям в разных таблицах?

Tags: php, mysql

Существует POST запрос и соответственный запрос в базу.

```
   $q = $_POST['q'];    
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `kvitan` WHERE `cena` LIKE '%".$q."%' OR `naimenov` LIKE '%".$q."%' LIMIT 20");
```

Как распарсить POST данные и задать правильный запрос в базу при условии, что в `$q` может быть и одна фраза, и несколько, сожержимое которых может находиться в одной таблице, но в разных колонках? Например: фраза "чайник 500 черный", где "чайник" и "черный" это данные из колонки "naimenov", а 500 из колонки "cena"??

Comment: Ну здесь либо [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), либо прикрутить поисковую систему типа [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Я бы выбрал последнее.

Comment: В MySQL возможности полнотекстового поиска (только для MyISAM-таблиц) поддерживаются начиная с версии 3.23.23. 
У меня InnoDB :(

Comment: Ну так Sphinx (или аналогичное) прикрутите, он лучше с этим справляется, чем full-text search

Comment: Пытался помочь, но как-то странно у вас одна переменная может соответствовать любой колонке...пересмотрите логику. Если пересмотреть не получается, тогда прикручивайте, как было сказано выше, Sphinx.

Comment: Решение "в лоб" - `$q` разбить в массив по разделителю пробел, а дальше запрос с условием вида `"CONCAT(`cena`, `naimenov`) LIKE '%" . $q[0] . "%' AND CONCAT(`cena`, `naimenov`) LIKE '%" . $q[1] . "%' ..."`. Не лучший поиск, но пользоваться можно.

Comment: Хорошо, согласен. Как составить запрос, если будет 2-3-4-5 слов?? Разбить на количество слов, посчитать, а дальше строить цикл while на количество слов и отправлять одиним запросом? Или есть другие варианты?